# Identive CLOUD 4710F transparent ICC command ADPU

Tags: nfc

I have an Identive Cloud 4710f reader.

I can "talk" with the reader but then I need to send a transparent ICC command and I cannot find a way to build a proper ADPU for that.

I need to send the PWD_AUTH command for NTAG21x ultralight ICCs that would be 0x1B followed by four bytes (the password).

I tried the envelope command `FF C2 00 00 05 1B 00 00 00 00 00` envelope but, as much as it executes fine (9000 returned), the data is `C0 03 00 6A 81` no matter what I send.

How do I send a transparent command with that reader?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to issue a transparent ICC command with the reader.

Documentation for the reader offers two commands:

- TCL_PASS_THRU --> Does not work for it always returns me a "function in class not implemented" (?)
- ISO14443_PART3_PASS_THRU --> This one works with a caveat.

So, the command APDU will be: `FF EF 00 00 05 1B pw1 pw2 pw3 pw4`
And it will return the NTAG PACK.
Please note that the response APDU will not contain the reader success return code (90 00) at all.

This information is relevant only for the Identive CLOUD readers.

Hope it helps.
Edoardo.